# JAX-WS Web Services and Eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jax-ws

I saw several tutorials on the web about creating web services, but If I look at the Eclipse Dynamic Web Project structure it seems to me that there should be a kind of "build-in" way to create those web services

[image]

So, is there a tutorial **specific** for adding web services to an existing Dynamic Web Project and that will end up **showing them under JAX-WS Web Services folder** (indicated by the arrow in the image above)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those should be populated if the module contains a JAX-WS web service.

To see an item show up under `Service Endpoint Interfaces`, create a Java interface which is annotated with `javax.jws.WebService`:

```
package org.example.sampleservice;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface SampleService {

    @WebMethod
    String sayHello(String name);
}
```

Produces:

[image: populated Service Endpoint Interface in eclipse 4.4]

To populate the `Web Services` tree, create a web service implementation class. Note this example implements the service endpoint interface; this is not a technical requirement. In other words, you can populate one and not the other. Only this step will actually produce a functional web service implementation within the module (and the eclipse UI you mention):

```
package org.example.sampleservice;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.example.sampleservice.SampleService")
@HandlerChain(file="handlers.xml")
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }

}
```

[image: populated eclipse Web Services tree]

Comment: Hi, thank'you very much! One more question? How to publish / consume that service? If I run my project on tomcat 7 server, which URL will have my WS? Something like http://localhost:8080/SampleService/webservices/SampleServiceImpl

Comment: Ok I got the answer... I need to first deploy the webservice as described here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/ (with Eclipse you can skip point 4)